# Putting list of data fetched from database into an email

Tags: c#, email

Basically. I have this project and I connect with tables from databases and lists info which I need. No I am trying to send an email which works perfectly. My only problems is what to put in the message body for the data listed in the console application to show in the email. Below is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;  
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

namespace sql_connection
{
 class Program
  {
static void Main(string[] args)
{





    string conn = null;
    SqlConnection connection;
    conn= ("Data Source=Databse\\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=Data_base;User ID=user;Password=example");

    connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
    try{

        connection.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Connection Open!");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Data_base].[dbo].[tb_Work].Date,[Data_base].[dbo].[tb_Work].FromTime,[Data_base].[dbo].[tb_Work].ToTime, [Data_base].[dbo].[tb_Work].User,[Data_base].[dbo].[tb_Login].Email FROM [Data_base].[dbo].[tb_Work]INNER JOIN [Data_base].[dbo].[tb_Login] ON [Data_base].[dbo].[tb_Work].whd_User = [Data_base].[dbo].[tb_Login].Login WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,[Date],GETDATE())<=7 AND   (ToTime = '' OR ToTime IS NULL) AND(User=Login)");
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while(reader.Read())
        {


              Console.WriteLine("{4},{3},{2}, {1}, {0}",
               reader["ToTime"] == DBNull.Value? "NULL" : reader["ToTime"].ToString(), 
               reader["FromTime"] == DBNull.Value? "NULL" : reader["FromTime"].ToString(), 
               reader["Date"].ToString(), 
               reader["User"].ToString(),
               reader["Email"].ToString()); 




        }


        connection.Close();


        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("email@gmail.com");


        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("email@gmail.com");

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to);


        mail.Subject = ("subject");

        mail.Body = (reader["ToTime"] == DBNull.Value? "NULL" : reader["ToTime"].ToString(), 
               reader["FromTime"] == DBNull.Value? "NULL" : reader["FromTime"].ToString(), 
               reader["Date"].ToString(), 
               reader["User"].ToString(),
               reader["Email"].ToString()); 
 );

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;

        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
            "example@gmail.com", "pass");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Sending email..");
        smtp.Send(mail);
    } 




    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }





    }
  }
}
```

As you can see in the Mail.body I tried to put again what I put in the console.writeline which made everything I needed show but for some reason it doesn't want to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Underneath a small change: you close your reader after the while loop, by reaccessing it, nothing will change as it is closed by then.

Fill a list while the reader is open and then create your mail based upon the list values.

```
var list = new List<string>();

while(reader.Read())
{   
    var s = string.Format("{4},{3},{2}, {1}, {0}",
               reader["ToTime"] == DBNull.Value? "NULL" : reader["ToTime"].ToString(), 
               reader["FromTime"] == DBNull.Value? "NULL" : reader["FromTime"].ToString(), 
               reader["Date"].ToString(), 
               reader["User"].ToString(),
               reader["Email"].ToString()); 
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    list.Add(s);
}

//create a full string of your list.
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var s in list)
{
    sb.AppendLine(s);
}

//set the mail body
mail.Body = sb.ToString();
```

Hope this helps

Extra:
When you know in which sequence your data comes in, you can also use the following syntax:

```
while(reader.Read())
{   
    var s = string.Format("{4},{3},{2}, {1}, {0}",
               reader.IsDBNull(0) ? "NULL" : reader.GetString(0),
               reader.IsDBNull(1) ? "NULL" : reader.GetString(1), 
               reader.IsDBNull(2) ? "NULL" : reader.GetString(2), 
               reader.IsDBNull(3) ? "NULL" : reader.GetString(3), 
               reader.IsDBNull(4) ? "NULL" : reader.GetString(4));
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    list.Add(s);
}
```

This makes it more readable

Comment: hi i think this should work the only problem in list.add(s)  the word add it says tdoes not contain a definition for add

Comment: nevermind it worked just add had to start in capital A

Answer (score 0):

The `reader.Read()` should move the cursor to the next record. What I think is happening is that you are running are iterating through all your items and then try to access them again (assuming you are expecting to see the data belonging to the last item?).

What you could do, would be to create a wrapper object which has the properties you are reading from your database. Within the block below:

```
    while(reader.Read())
    {
          Console.WriteLine("{4},{3},{2}, {1}, {0}",
           reader["ToTime"] == DBNull.Value? "NULL" : reader["ToTime"].ToString(), 
           reader["FromTime"] == DBNull.Value? "NULL" : reader["FromTime"].ToString(), 
           reader["Date"].ToString(), 
           reader["User"].ToString(),
           reader["Email"].ToString()); 
    }
```

You instead initialize said wrapper object and place it in a list. You could override the `ToString()` method so that you can print it to console or somewhere else.

Within your email construction section, you would then iterate over the list you would have created (the one containing the wrapper objects) and create the email with the information you need.